# Is the MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup installer command line parameters documented? And return values?

Tags: webview2

Microsoft have the [WebView2 Runtime bootstrapper](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=2124703) called:

`MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup`

The document states that we should use these parameters: `/silent /install`.

- Is there an official list of the possible parameters?
- Is there an official list of the return values (eg. in case PC needs restart etc.)

I tried running it at the console window with `/h` and `/?`' and it didn't like them.